# How calculator's processor works in a base manner?

Tags: cpu, processor, calculator

For example, when we click the "3" number button or "+" button, what it sends to processor ? I want an answer something like = " It come first MAR, then goes to Memory, then comes ALU " in this manner I want to learn this processing steps. Thank you from now.

Edit: I especially don't get, how and from where processor take the input and understand we push the button "3".

Comment: Read this website: http://www.explainthatstuff.com/calculators.html

Comment: @12Lappie I literally did the same thing. "How calculators work?" -> Googles first result.
Also, what kind of calculator? You can get really basic calculators to very complex graphing calculators (Like TI-Nspire models)

Comment: I actually want to learn about fetch/execute cycle of it. In this link, I can't find an answer to my question. Please think about most easy working calculator.

Comment: 3 -> binary: 011, "+" is the same thing as OR. So if you add 3+2, you're really "OR-ing" 011 and 010 to get 101 for the number 5.

Comment: he pcboard design is well known to everyone (relevant) at the company making the product, the software engineer will know that button 3 for example is wired to portA pin 7, and button "4" to port b pin 2, and so on, so in software they have a map of what pin on the chip is wired to what button

Comment: So after we push "3" button, an electric signal will be sent to portA pin7. After this, what will happen ? When we take electric signal on this spesific pin, we will understand it is the number "3" from ROM ?

Comment: Your use of Calculator (which is usually a state machine driven ALU) and processor has really messed up this question.  This is more a Google question.

Comment: @KingDuken 011b OR 010b = 011b.  OR is NOT addition.

Answer (score 1):

the buttons are all individually wired, either one wire per or a row column matrix.  for example one side of the switch can be tied to ground the other to a pin on the mcu, with a pull up in the mcu.  When the button is pressed the signal is pulled low.  For battery powered calculators the processor is ideally sleeping waiting for an interrupt to save power, either way it gets an interrupt or is polling the keyboard.  It knows from the input which button that is and adds that value into a software parser that handles the inputs. From there is is like any other software on any other processor, you parse the input and take the appropriate actions.  The displays are generally really low power as well and some have a separate signal per segment, a separate pin per, this way the mcu sofware can turn some on and some off then go to sleep and they stay in that state.

Like the keyboard they know from the wiring of the board/design which pin is which segment and to "print" the number 3 out in the first column which 5 segments need to be turned on and which two or three to be turned off.  Repeat for the rest of the display.

I can then get as much more complicated as you want or are willing to pay for, you can have a processor dedicated to the keyboard like we do with our computers, and one dedicated to the display and then one for doing the operations, in those cases then you would define a protocol between them (like we have with our keyboards on our computers/laptops), a bit wasteful for something like a calculator that only has to outrun the human pushing buttons at human speeds.

There is no magic to it if that is what you were hoping, you have some sort of switch or way to detect a button "press" using some technology, again either one per button or a row column approach will give you a unique answer per button (row/column wont work if they press two). then it is just software from there on.

EDIT

If you are interested in fetch/execute a calculator is not remotely the easiest way to think about it there is a lot of basic stuff going on just to handle the keystroke.  Just think about a simple program running machine code from ram instead if you are interested in processor pipelines.

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    return(a+b+3);
}
```

giving

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e2811003    add r1, r1, #3
   4:   e0810000    add r0, r1, r0
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

One operand is in register r0 the other in register r1.  The processor fetches the first instruction 0xe2811003, then it decodes it, then it determines it needs to read the contents of r1 as an input.  Then those contents and the constant 3 are added together.  Then the result is saved (written to) r1.  Either in parallel or separate depending on the design the processor fetches the next instruction. 0xe0810000, decodes it, determines it is an add and it needs to read operands from r0 and r1, add those values together and then save the result in r0.

Doesnt matter whether this is a calculator or web browser or operating system program it is just a sequence of instructions the processor grinds thorugh.  The sequence means absolutely nothing to the processor they only mean something to the programmer.  When dealing with keyboards or mice or video cards or hard drives it is just the same a sequence of instructions being fed through the processor that doesnt care what they mean as a group.

Well known/defined address spaces for that processor or computer determine whether you are talking to ram or to a peripheral.  The pcboard is well known to the board and chip and software engineers such that they know what is connected to what and/or a generic interface (usb, etc) which is also well defined as to how it works how you communicate over it, etc.

A calculator is just one application, not actually that simple as you have to do it without wearing out the battery, ideally a year or more but who knows.  And you have to do complicated math with an ideally wee bitty low power processor, so lots of math tricks are involved and/or a very good power savings scheme within the processor (multiply blocks only enable the clocks during a multiply perhaps), although I dont think they do that as there are some that are known to have generic mcus in them rather than something exotic, but at the end of the day it is just a collection of instructions that mean nothing to the cpu, the cpu has no direct connection to the peripherals itself there are interfaces on chip that do that (between the cpu core and the edge of the chip), GPIO pins, one for each key on the keyboard for example.

Answer (score 1):

It really starts what's inside of an ALU. Excuse the bad quality of the picture, I captured it from PDF version of a textbook called, "Computer Organization and Design". I'll try to make this short and sweet.
[image]

As you can see here, this is what's inside a 1-bit ALU. You can see the AND, OR, summation of \$ a \$ and \$ b \$, and then the LESS THAN flag. There's also a SET and OVERFLOW flag detection. Now we're going to combine 32 of these guys to make a 32-bit ALU.

[image]

Now we can add larger numbers to get a result from 0 to 4294967296. This 32-bit ALU also comes with an OR gate at the end for a ZERO flag detection. So if you add 0+0, the ZERO flag with be raised an you will get 0 as an answer. All numbers are in binary... for instance if you add 3+2, you're really performing 000...011 OR 000...010 to get 000...101 which is 5 in binary.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually asking how a small computer does mathematics. Have a look on the internet for 'software maths routines', the should be plenty there.

The fact that the CPU is an embedded system in a calculator won't affect the relevance of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

The buttons on a calculator are arranged in rectangular grids.  The tracks on the circuit board are arranged in columns and rows, with copper pads on each column and row under each button.  On the back of each button will be either a springy piece of metal, or a blob of conductive rubber.  So when you press a button, it connects one row and one column together.

The calculator checks what button you're pressing by applying a voltage to each row in turn, and seeing if anything appears on a column.  Or the other way round if it's easier for the manufacturer.

On the calculator in front of me, the 7, 8, 9 and X buttons are on the 3rd row.  If the microprocessor applies a voltage to the 3rd row, and sees a voltage coming back on the 2nd column, then it knows I have pressed the 8.